# CSS format dl tag horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I have markup that looks like the following:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Item 1</dt>
    <dd>a</dd>

    <dt>Item 2</dt>
    <dd>b</dd>

    <dt>Item 3</dt>
    <dd>c</dd>

    <dt>Item 4</dt>
    <dd>d</dd>
</dl>
```

I would like to style it to look like the following:

[image: Definition List formatted horizontally and vertically]

I have attempted all sorts of things but keep coming back to needing to change the markup. Is there a way to do this cleanly with only CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Is it **extremely** necessary to use dl/dt/dd? This could be easily solved with ul/li such as

```
<style>
    ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    li {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>
        a
        <p>Item 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        b
        <p>Item 2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        c
        <p>Item 3</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        d
        <p>Item 4</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I don't believe you can get the expected result without a little change on the markup.

Comment: It isn't extremely necessary, but I want to maintain the cleanest possible separation of presentation and content.

Comment: For doing what you want to do you absolutely need a container around dt+dd, and that would not be W3C recommended if using dt+dd. I'd recommend you switch to a different markup structure such as the suggested.

Comment: @VitorRigoni If you change `li p {` to `li {` it will center the text as asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you ***can*** get the desired result without changing the markup/HTML.

Check it out: http://codepen.io/n3ptun3/pen/dYEOYm?editors=110

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Item 1</dt>
    <dd>a</dd>

    <dt>Item 2</dt>
    <dd>b</dd>

    <dt>Item 3</dt>
    <dd>c</dd>

    <dt>Item 4</dt>
    <dd>d</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dl {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

dt, dd {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

dt {
  top: 25px;
}

dt:nth-child(3), dd:nth-child(4)  {
  left: 100px;
}

dt:nth-child(5), dd:nth-child(6)  {
  left: 200px;
}

dt:nth-child(7), dd:nth-child(8)  {
  left: 300px;
}
```

Comment: it works – albeit you are limited by fixed widths and positioning. It gets messed up if content expands

Comment: this is true, Herr_Schwabullek. However, this does fix the OP's issue with the given requirements and content. It can be adjusted, as needed.